# $f_{n}(x)= x^n+n\sqrt x-1 $. Prove that $a_{n+1} < a_{n}$

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, first-order-logic

$f_{n}(x)= x^n+n\sqrt x-1$

*We already proved the following:*

- $f_{n+1}(a_n)= a_n^{n+1} + \sqrt{a_n} \cdot(1-a_n^{n-1}\sqrt{a_n}) $
- $a_{n}$ is a solution to $f_{n}(x)=0$
- $0 < a_{n} < 1$

**1- Prove that $a_{n+1} < a_{n}$**

*Then, we also prove that $0 < a_{n} < 1/n^2$*

**2- Prove that: $\frac{1}{n}$ - $\frac{1}{n^2+1}$ < $\sqrt{a_n}$ < $\frac{1}{n}$**

here is an image of the exercise to help:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLRtE.jpg)

*Thank you so much in advance*

Comment: I tried to math-ify these formulae, bit in one place is is / was missing a `)`, and I don't want to guess.

Comment: I am not 100% sure either, but for sure the square root does not include what is in the parentheses. In this way the formula works and is similar to what is in the picture (there is probably a sign typo in the picture)

Answer (score 1):

We can prove $a_{n+1}<a_n$ by directly substituting $x=a_n$ into $f_n(x)$ and with what was already proven by OP,

\begin{align}(a_n)^{n+1}+(n+1)\sqrt{a_n}-1&=(a_n)^{n+1}+\sqrt{a_n}(1-(a_n)^{n-1}\sqrt{a_n})\\(a_n)^n&=n\sqrt{a_n}
-1\\(a_n)^n-n\sqrt{a_n}-1&=0\tag{*}\end{align}
To prove $a_{n+1}<a_n$, we can show that for increasing values of $n$, that $a_n$ will need to decrease to satisfy equation $(*)$. Here is a graphical interpretation (as you move the slider for $n$; try it out for yourself!):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the function $f_{n+1}$ is strictly increasing, to show that $a_{n+1} < a_n$, we only need to show that $f_{n+1}(a_n) >0$. This follows from :
$$f_{n+1}(a_n) = a_n^{n+1} + \sqrt{a_n} (1-\sqrt{a_n} a_n^{n-1})$$
as $\sqrt{a_n} a_n^{n-1} <1$.

Likewise, we can show that $a_n < \frac{1}{n^2}$ by remarking that $f_n(\frac{1}{n^2}) = \frac{1}{n^{2n}}>0$.

Comment: thanks very much :) but what about the other part of the comparison of the second question?

Comment: Use the same technique as I used for the first two inequations.